# Changing a view programmatically to align left or right

Tags: swift, interface-builder, ios9, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint

I have been building this chat and I am stuck in something that  I can't figure out yet.

I have been unsuccessfully trying to align the same view left or right according to the scenario but I haven't gotten the desired result yet.

Basically, I built the cell in interface builder and pinned to the left and made its width and height variable according to the contents of the labels inside.

What I have been trying to do is reusing the same cell and align to the right when the I am the one sending the message (yellow) because by default it will be aligned to the left when others send me a message (gray) see the following image for illustration:

[image]

What I want is:

others messages--------

--------------my message

To accomplish this, and under TroyT's suggestion, I activated and deactivated the leading/trailing constraints according to my needs.

So what I did was.

1. On my UITableViewCell Class, I created two @IBoulets for my two constraints like so:

   @IBOutlet var bubbleViewLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!

   @IBOutlet var bubbleViewTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint!
2. Later, in my tableViewController  on the method **cellForRowAtIndexPAth** , I activate or deactivate one of the constraints according to my needs doing the following.

`cell.bubbleViewTrailing.active = true
 cell.bubbleViewLeading.active = false`

or the opposite

`cell.bubbleViewTrailing.active = false
 cell.bubbleViewLeading.active = true`

where the constraint set to "True" is set to 0. As I mentioned before, this work well for all cells except the first one.

3. This works PARTIALLY, because for some reason it does not affect the first row and both constraints stay activated, hence the row is stretched through the tableview's width like so:.

[image]

I tried several things like:

- Using the init method from my UITableViewCell class to change the constraints
- Changing the constraints from the awakeFromNib method within my UITableViewCell
- Using the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" on the 3rd tab from the left on the storyboard, add a key path named "active", set the type to Bool, and set the value to false.
- unticking "installed" in the attribute inspector when I select the constraints in the storyboard

However, none of these methods affect the constraints on the first cell but I can easily change everything else like the cell background or the text alignment in a label within the cell. It just the constraint that will not change for that first time that I use the cell. Even when I scroll down past the boundaries of the screen to "force" the cell reuse, the first cell becomes fixed:

[image]

I have been trying to figure this one out for days with little success. Hence, I decided to put a bounty on this question.

Comment: you want to align chat cell according to sender and receiver. sender cell with right align and receiver with left align using constraints, right ?

Comment: keshav vishwkarma, that is right and I'm doing it well except for that first cell

Comment: how you are dealing with  the constraints? I mean using either active property of view to activate/deactivate constraint or remove/add constraint

Comment: In the storyboard I initially created two constraints from the bubble view to the cell margins. I created this from a custom cell .xib where I set both the leading and the trailing constraints to 0. So the result is what happens in the first cell as you may have seen in the screenshots. I, however, thought that by setting the constraints active property to true or false would give me the desired result. However, this is partially true as it does not apply to the first cell that appears in my table view

Comment: I have implemented ChatMessageCell for you please check my answer below & I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you explain makes little sense to me, but if it is happening only with the first row, then I would try forcing the layout to redraw by doing:

`cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()`

from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

BTW, I think a better approach would be to register 2 different cells, and create them both in IB. This approach will keep your code shorter and will allow you to modify not only the trailing/leading but also colors, fonts or whatever you need. You give them 2 different IDs, but keep the same implementation class, and you just deque the one you need on your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Keeping a different cell per style is the standard way to do these things with IB.

Comment: I had tried these  `cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before and does not work for me. I also tried the 2 cell method but I was getting an error but your comment made me realize what I was doing wrong (I was using different xibs in the tableView.registerNib but the same id for dequeuing) . Thank you!! Will update my question for the future newbies like me

Answer (score 1):

`removeConstraint:` is deprecated, in favor of using the `active` property instead (or `NSLayoutConstraint`'s `deactivateConstraints:`). While `removeConstraint:` still usually works, combining that with setting your constraints' `active` property makes this worse. Either use all activate and deactivate (preferred) or use add and remove.

So instead of `cell.removeConstraint:`, use this:

```
cell.bubbleViewTrailing.active = false
```

One thing I may note is that your leading and trailing is reversed. Leading is on the left and trailing is on the right, except for right-to-left localization.

Comment: your observation seems accurate but still having the same issue, I will try to see what else could be happening, I did correct the reversed leading/trailing  confusion that I had: `NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.bubbleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
            cell.bubbleViewLeading.active = false`

Comment: your answer guided me in the right way, would you mind checking my updated problem? works well except in the first cell, is there any cell preparation between Interface builder and prepareForReuse?

Comment: Try calling it in `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` and deactivate the constraints (make sure you call `super.init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` first!). Keep the `prepareForReuse` implementation since the `init` will be called on creation and `prepareForReuse` will be called for the recycled ones.

Comment: Tried that to no avail, still not being able to modify the constraints in that first cell. However, I can modify everything else, except for the constraints, I can modify its colour, text alignment. Those constraints in the first cell are stubborn! I thought that maybe the outlets that I created were wrong but that is not it because from the second cell forward, they work well

Comment: @Granola Why don't you just deactivate it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: that is what I have been doing since the beginning but for some reason it does not affect the constraints for the very first cell. Actually, even if I scroll outside to force cell reausage, everything works like a charm

Comment: @Granola Try unchecking "Installed" for the constraints in the storyboard, and then activating them in code.

Comment: @Granola Or, you can go into "User Defined Runtime Attributes" on the 3rd tab from the left on the storyboard, add a key path named "active", set the type to Bool, and set the value to false.

Comment: I also tried that  just that first cell ignores constraints changes. It made me think that constraints need a special treatment for them to work before the first time

Comment: = false crashes for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Custom `ChatMessageCell` that I have implemented for you in which I have applied programmatically constrains using the [KVConstraintExtensionsMaster](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster)  library to apply constraints that I have implemented.

I have update the leading & trailing constraints Constant value instead of activate/deactivate constraint or remove/add constraint.

I hope this may help you.

Put below code in `ChatMessageCell.h` header file

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Type) {
    TypeSender,
    TypeReceiver,
};

@interface ChatMessageCell : UITableViewCell

@property (assign, nonatomic) Type cellType;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *msgBackgroundView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *messageLabel;

@end
```

Put below code in `ChatMessageCell.m` file

```
#import "ChatMessageCell.h"
#import "KVConstraintExtensionsMaster.h"

@implementation ChatMessageCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self createAndConfigureViewHierarchy];
    }    
    return self;
}

- (void)createAndConfigureViewHierarchy
{
    _msgBackgroundView = [UIView prepareNewViewForAutoLayout];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_msgBackgroundView];

    _msgBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [_msgBackgroundView.layer setCornerRadius:6.0];

    _labelMessage = [UILabel prepareNewViewForAutoLayout];
    [_labelMessage setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    [_labelMessage setNumberOfLines:0];
    [_labelMessage setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [_labelMessage setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.labelMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [_msgBackgroundView addSubview:_labelMessage];

    [self applyConstraints];
}

-(void)applyConstraints
{
    // now applying the constraints by using KVConstraintExtensionsMaster library
    CGFloat padding = 8.0;

    // adding Top and Bottom contraints of _msgBackgroundView
    [_msgBackgroundView applyTopAndBottomPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:padding];

    // adding leading and trailing contraints of _msgBackgroundView
    [_msgBackgroundView applyLeadingAndTrailingPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:padding];

    // adding Top and Bottom contraints of _msgBackgroundView
    [_labelMessage applyTopAndBottomPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:padding];

    // adding leading and trailing contraints of _msgBackgroundView
    [_labelMessage applyLeadingAndTrailingPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:padding];

}

-(void)setCellType:(Type)cellType
{
    switch (cellType) {
        case TypeSender:
        {
            [_msgBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [_labelMessage setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

            // this method will change the Leading Pin Constraint Constant value by 100.0
            [_msgBackgroundView applyLeadingPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:100.0];

            // this method will increase the Leading Pin Constraint Constant value with proper ratio only iPad
            [_msgBackgroundView updateAppliedConstraintConstantValueForIpadByAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading];
            break;
        }

        case TypeReceiver:
        {
            [_msgBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [_labelMessage setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

            // this method will change the Trailing Pin Constraint Constant value by 100.0
            [_msgBackgroundView applyTrailingPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:100.0];

            // this method will increase the Leading Pin Constraint Constant value with proper ratio only iPad
            [_msgBackgroundView updateAppliedConstraintConstantValueForIpadByAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing];
            break;
        }
    }

    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.contentView updateModifyConstraints];
}

-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    // this method will change the Leading And Trailing Pin Constraints Constant value by 8.0
    [_msgBackgroundView applyLeadingAndTrailingPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:8.0];
    [super prepareForReuse];
}

@end
```

Put the below code in the viewDidLoad method ofyour ViewController is:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:ChatMessageCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"KVChatMessageCell"];
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
/* any estimated height but must be more than 2 */
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

Now implement UITableView DataSource in your ViewController

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section{
    return messages.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"KVChatMessageCell";

    ChatMessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.labelMessage setText:messages[indexPath.row]];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
       // here all even cell are the sender type
        [cell setCellType:TypeSender];
    }
    else {
       // here all odd cell are the Receiver type
        [cell setCellType:TypeReceiver];
    }

    return cell;
}
```